# Truncated value is being stored

Tags: c, arrays, char, hex

Here is my buffer and can any one explain how can i store a hexadecimal value inside this and when i try to print `buffer[0]`, it is printing 0 instead of 500. I am trying to fill an element of the buffer with the ID which is of 11bits, I know the char is of 1 byte i.e.,8 bits and it cannot store the value. i have other elements to be filled into buffer and they are of type char. So i cannot change the type of the buffer from char to int. How can I solve my problem.

```
char *buffer;
buffer = (char *)malloc(10*(sizeof(frameRd)));      //frameRd is of 16bytes
buffer[0] = frameRd->id;
for(int i =1;i<15;i++)
{
  buffer[i] = frameRd->data;
}
for(int i =0,i<16;i++)
{
 printf("%4X",buffer[i]);
}
```

where `frame->id = 0x500;` when i print this value on console, it is printing `buffer[0]` as 0 and surely because

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem for example `frameRd` is not shown. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: The least significant byte of `0x500` is `0` and `buffer` is a pointer to `char`.

Comment: Please stop tinkering with the question and post the MCVE as asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `buffer` is `char*`, `buffer[0]` is `char`. Therefore, the assignment

```
buffer[0] = frameRd->id;
```

means "truncate `frameRd->id` to `char`, and store the result in `buffer[0]`," i.e. exactly the effect that you are observing. Moreover, when you print `buffer[0]` with `%4X`, you print the value of `buffer[0]` alone, converted to `int`.

If you want to get an `int` or a whole `struct` into a `char[]` buffer, use `memcpy`:

```
// Do not cast results of malloc
buffer = malloc(10*(sizeof(frameRd)));
// Save id into the buffer at index 0
memcpy(&buffer[0], &frameRd->id, sizeof(frameRd->id));
// Pull id back
int tmpId;
memcpy(&tmpId, &buffer[0], sizeof(tmpId));
printf("%04x\n", tmpId);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/3CuhvL)

Comment: After that if i print my buffer elements from 0 to 15, am I able to see the `frameRd->id` value as it is?

Comment: @user8540390 Since `id` is multi-byte, if you print `buffer`'s bytes individually, you will be able to see individual bytes representing `frameRd->id` in computer-specific order. You may see either `00 00 50 00` or `00 50 00 00`, depending on the CPU architecture.